# OpenGL Binding Points

Tags: opengl

What are the advantages of using binding points in OpenGL? Why the following code:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, textureName);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Is not something like?

```
glTexParameteri(textureName, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Comment: There is no advantage to doing it that way, it is that way for historical reasons. Most of the quirky things in the GL API are the way they are because it is so darn hard to get anything to change. That said, what you are asking for ***has*** been implemented in the form of [`GL_EXT_direct_state_access`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/direct_state_access.txt) -- `void glTextureParameteriEXT (GLuint texture, GLenum target, GLenum pname, GLint param);`. However, only AMD and NV implement this extension, even though it is > 5 years old.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I thought it was done on purpose

Comment: I am sure when the API was first designed, there was a reason for using a selector mechanism to set the "current" object for commands to apply to... probably either for display lists or simply to reduce the number of arguments passed and shorten the number of characters per-line. But ultimately it is more of a nuisance in modern GL, which is why I really wish the DSA extension were more widely adopted.

Comment: It also serves as a convoluted way of telling OpenGL what type of texture you are dealing with. Obviously it could have been done in a cleaner way, but as Andron said, they kept that old method for historical reasons. Even with GL_EXT_direct_state_access functions, you must pass a texture target (i.e. GL_TEXTURE_2D, etc).